# Optimize webpage speed with lots of graphics

Tags: html, optimization, download, performance

We just finished this webpage http://marinosactiongrill.com/, as you can see its HUGE and it has a lot of graphics (almost 7M), that make it download very slow on the first time (aprox 20 to 40 secs)

Can you help me with tips to make show more fast?

I know that its better to use sprites... but i couldnt find a way to make responsive buttons and animations with sprite that is also compatible between IE and other browsers

Regards...

Comment: I took a random image in your page: `slider01.jpg`. 186KB. This is WAY too much, for the dimensions of the image. You can divide by at least 10 the size of your images if all are following this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with you might want to consider using [Google Page Speed plugin](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) - it can help you with analyzing your performance bottlenecks.

**1)** By scaling and optimizing images you can save up to ~500kb of your initial loading. Also you should think of using jpg compressed images instead of png format. jpg is a lossy format but can save some bandwidth compared to png-s.

**2)** Setting up correct server-side caching can also work wonders - instead of loading static content on every request you can just cache it after first request.

**3)** There also seems to be something wrong with your server-side setup - loading relatively small and static css and javascript files takes up to 2 seconds in some cases. Is your server under heavy load?

**4)** In modern browsers your page doesn't have to be built using just images. Instead of making two sets of images for each button you can just use custom fonts + some new fancy css in order to achive "glowing" effect for mouseover. Here is a quick demo - http://jsfiddle.net/nc6v4/, it is done using only css, no images.

```
some-selector {
    font-family: /*Name for custom font loaded for example via google api*/
    box-shadow: /*Use for blurry outlines, glowing effect etc*/
    background: /*You can use for example gradients instead of using images*/
}
```

**5)** Do not host jquery in your own server - use some kind of CDN - jquery provides it's own CDN and if you are not comfortable with it, use one provided either by google or microsoft.

**6)** Server-side compression can save up a lot of bandwidth - in your case ~500kb of data. Instead of passing your html, java-script and css as a plain text, "gzip" it, use correct HTTP header and browser will automatically uncompress it.

**7)** One last but rather important technique - combine your javascript files into one big minified javascript file. The thing is, when making lots of request to server at the same time, those requests will start blocking each other. It is MUCH faster to load 1 file which has size of 20kb rather than 20 files with size of 1kb. Use same technique for css.

**To sum it all up** - there is no magical technique to make this site fast by using just couple of lines of code. When you set up server-side caching and combine +minify your java-script and css files you should be fine though. When extra performance is desired, consider using modern css + html techniques instead of bandwidth heavy images.

**Also, as a quick side note**, your page doesn't have to look 100% identical across all browsers. Modern browsers perform seamless auto-updates, keeping up with new standards and old versions of internet explorer are losing their market share at quite a satisfactory rate. Furthermore, since target audience for your page seems to be gamers, browser compatibility also shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance of your website you need Firebug and PageSpeed together (Firefox) or PageSpeed ​​(Google Chrome). These tools can help you to improve also other bottlenecks that you haven't found yet.

*Online Tool
 
http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
*Extension for Google Chrome and Firefox 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights_extensions
*Firebug
https://getfirebug.com/downloads/
To use it in Firefox, you need to install Firebug and PageSpeed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back and optimize your images as they are far too big given their dimensions. If you used photoshop its just a case of file > save as for web > and then finding the balance between compression artifacts and file sizes.

It could also be beneficial to use something like [Pictue Fill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) which loads versions of images for certain resolutions making the site much quicker as you go down in screen sizes. Why bother loading massive images that just get scaled down for lower screen sizes!

Its as easy as;

```
<span data-picture data-alt="Image Description">
    <span data-src="small.jpg"></span>
    <span data-src="medium.jpg"     data-media="(min-width: 400px)"></span>
    <span data-src="large.jpg"      data-media="(min-width: 800px)"></span>
    <span data-src="extralarge.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)"></span>
```

This might be too much work, but it is definitely something to consider.